# error: 'Invalid Authorization. Your account does not have access to the PayWhirl API.'

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to integrate Paywhirl API on my App

```
            const PayWhirl = require('paywhirl');

            const apiKey = 'pwpk_608a4caae2acc608a4caae2ace';
            const apiSecret = 'pwpsk_608a4caae2aed608a4caae2aee';

            const paywhirl = new PayWhirl(apiKey, apiSecret);

            paywhirl.getAccount().then(console.log);
```

But I got this issue

[image]

Answer (score 0):

API access to PayWhirl is limited to paid PayWhirl accounts! Should you get the message "Invalid Authorization. Your account does not have access to the PayWhirl API." you're probably on the free PayWhirl plan. You'll need to upgrade or ask PayWhirl management.